# Should we ignore Solution Output folder while we are using Visual Studio and Version Control?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, visual-studio, svn, bazaar

I'm using Bazaar and Visual Studio 2010 in a C# project. I have prepared an ignore list but still I think all the files in Solution Output directory could be ignored.

I search a lot but nobody had mentioned it. So I'm going to know if I can ignore this directory because output files are changing regularly and seems are not important for repository copy.

What do you suggest about this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, any file that is automatically generated by compiler or build tools should NOT be committed into source control. This includes object files, executables, generated resource files, symbols, etc. Committing those files does not serve any useful purpose. Also, sometimes there are configuration files which look like can be committed, but really should not if they only contain local user specific info - for Visual Studio there are `*.user` files.

By that logic, solution output folder should be always put into ignore list.

Comment: For example, QtCreator suggests output directory outside of the source dir. So it seems like a good idea.